# WPF ComboBox SelectionChanged event to command not firing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have the following XAML of a `ComboBox` which has a code-behind `SelectionChanged` event handler and another Command property of the ViewModel. I have set the `SelectedIndex` property to 0. Now when I run the project, the code-behind handler is invoked, but the `Command` is not executed. What I want is that the `Command` should be executed for `SelectedIndex=0` the first time the View is loaded.

```
<ComboBox Name="listComboBox" SelectionChanged="listComboBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="Content" Margin="5,0" Height="35" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListTypeComboSelectionChangedCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="ItemOne" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="ItemTwo" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="ItemThree" />
</ComboBox>
```

**Update**

Code-behind event handler:

```cs
private void listComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) { }
```

ICommand object:

```cs
public ICommand ListTypeComboSelectionChangedCmd 
{ 
    get { return new RelayCommand<string>(ListTypeComboSelectionChangedCmdExec); }
    private set;
}
```

ICommand Handler:

```cs
private void ListTypeComboSelectionChangedCmdExec(string listType) { }
```

Comment: Why is this for? If you want something to happen just after the view as loaded why not do it *when* in loads? Also, no event will be fired for a SelectedIndex set in xaml at creation (not runtime).

Comment: You have an event and a command for the same thing. Get rid of the inline event call.

Comment: @Sinity, if the selectionchanged event for the first ComboBoxItem is fired right after the view is loaded, then why shouldn't the command execute ?

Comment: @Xcalibur37, even after I remove the SelectionChanged event handler the command does not execute.

Comment: @Lucifer, if so, post the code which fire the event you're talking about (after the view as loaded).

Comment: @Sinity, I have updated my question as per your request, but I not sure how much will it help.

Comment: What are you trying to do in ListTypeComboSelectionChangedCmdExec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bind `SelectedValue` to a `Property` on the view model.

In the `Property` `set{...}` block do your logic there or call

```
ListTypeComboSelectionChangedCmdExec(value)
```

See [Binding ComboBox SelectedItem using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632270/binding-combobox-selecteditem-using-mvvm)

Comment: That's a smart solution, but I would have preferred to keep the setter clean. Also I was more interested in knowing as to why such a functionality doesn't work, where the SelectionChanged event fires but it does not execute the underlying Command. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why not Bind SelectedValue to the Property, but in your view OnLoaded event handler, set it to the first value. Setter logic is sub optimal

Comment: @Lucifer bit late of a reply, but my guess would be that the event gets fired before the behaviour gets 'Attached'.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use handler in the code behind and connect it to ModelView as below.

```
var viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
if (viewModel.MyCommand.CanExecute(null))
    viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);
```

Please check this link: [Call Command from Code Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126968/call-command-from-code-behind)